# Multiple Browser Instance of unique profiles using CreateProcess() is not giving expected output

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, multiprocessing, thread-synchronization

I have multiple profiles in Chrome.Profile names are like - Profile 0,Profile 1,.... I am Opening multiple chrome instance with unique profile using CreateProcess(). After that I am assigning each process a thread using CreateThread().Now if i want to open 2 profiles like Profile 0 and Profile 1 using the below code whats happening is that Profile 0 and Profile 2 is opening.

I have a question if I create a Process then they create their threads and I know which thread is Of chrome.exe. So is there any way to join a function with CreateProcess() like in CreateThread() we can pass ThreadProcedure function.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

const int s = 125;   \\length of buffer containing Path of Chrome which I am giving in Commandline not in main but direectly to Create Process and it is absolutely fine.

using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(PVOID i)
{
    STARTUPINFOA si;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));

    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    DWORD dwPID = GetCurrentProcessId();

    wprintf(L"ThreadProc %d() process ID is %u\n",*(int*)i, dwPID);

    DWORD dwTID = GetCurrentThreadId();

    wprintf(L"ThreadProc %d() thread ID is %u\n",*(int*)i, dwTID);

    char cmdline[s];

    sprintf_s(cmdline,s,"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe --profile directory=\"Profile %d\" https://www.google.com", *((int*)i));

    if (CreateProcessA(0, cmdline, 0, 0, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        printf("Succed creating Process %d: ",*((int*)i));
        cout << "Proc Id-" << pi.dwProcessId << " Thread Id-" << pi.dwThreadId<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failure creating Process: %d",*((int*)i));
    }
    return(0);
}

int main()
{
    int profiles;
    printf("profiles count: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &profiles);  \\Number of Profiles I want to open

    DWORD* threadId=(DWORD*)malloc(sizeof(DWORD) * profiles);
    HANDLE* hThread= (HANDLE*)malloc(sizeof(HANDLE) * profiles);

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < profiles; i++)
    {
        hThread[i] = CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc, &i,0, &threadId[i]);

        if (hThread[i] == 0)
            cout << "Thread Creation Failed and Error Number->" << GetLastError();
        else
            cout << "Thread "<<i<< " Created->" << threadId[i] << endl;

    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(i,hThread,1,INFINITE);
}
```

Comment: Sharing `&i` across multiple threads without guarding against concurrent access to `*&i` isn't going to end well.

Comment: Ohh I see. Yes I am doing Multithreading for the first Time and There are not so much material about multi threading in The book "Programming Windows" by Petzold.Can you please give a brief idea how to do that.

Comment: Since all you really need is the *value* of `i` inside your thread procedure, why not simply pass the value instead of a pointer to the value? Multithreading is trivially simple, until you start using pointers/references.

Comment: iinspectable because ThreadProcedure takes PVOID means pointer to void. when i am passing i it is giving me error.I tried passing i by typecasting it to PVOID and in ThreadProcedute I typecasted it back to int. It then gives no error but Output is strange.

Comment: Though I got the solution someone Posted and deleted that. I dont knoow why he did that. But the solution is to use WaitForMutipleObjects() inside the for loop. I am giving the code below.

Comment: If the *"Output is strange"* then either conversion (or both) are wrong.

Comment: I have converted them correctly if I do something wrong then The Chrome instance will not open. It is opening but not in order like I am trying to open Profile 0 and profile 1 and it is giving me Profile 1 and Profile 2. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue here is sharing memory across threads without protecting against concurrent access. While the outer `for` loop continues spinning and updating the value stored in `i`, the spawned threads concurrently dereference the memory location `&i`.

Strictly speaking, the behavior of doing this is undefined, though in practice the spawned threads will observe a value of `0`, `1`, or `2` when dereferencing `&i`, depending on when they are looking.

None of this need to happen. In this case the spawned threads only really need the *value* of `i`, not a reference to it. The fix is as simple as passing the value, rather than a pointer to it:

```cpp
#include <Basetsd.h> // For the conversion helpers

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(PVOID pv) {
    auto const i{ PtrToInt(pv) };
    // Use i
    // ...
}

int main() {
    // ...
    int i{};
    for (; i < profiles; i++) {
        hThread[i] = CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc, IntToPtr(i), 0, &threadId[i]);
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

With those changes, the main thread and the spawned worker threads have been decoupled, and either one can make forward progress without depending on any other thread or data.

It is not required to use the `PtrToInt` and `IntToPtr` helpers. The type conversions can be done in C++, though it turns out to be rather verbose:

```cpp
// Inside ThreadProc
auto const i{ static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(pv)) };
```

```cpp
// Inside main
auto const pv{ reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<intptr_t>(i)) };
```

Comment: Perfect Man. Thank You .   How or from where do you aquire this knowledge?